# How to store database column in ArrayList in android?

Tags: android, arraylist

Here I want to store data in `ArrayList` visible Sections please help me...

Here's my code.

```
 public DataSingleton() {
    try {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/Download/Nanhikali_db.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select label from nanhikali where level = 1", null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String lb = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("label"));
                visibleSections.add(lb);
                visibleSections = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Then what's your problem?

Comment: add c.moveToFirst before while.

Comment: label is my column name and i want to store data in column to arraylist

Comment: it shows null pointer exception please help me ...........

Comment: 10-29 06:09:29.257 22681-22681/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 06:09:29.257 22681-22681/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sagarbluezone.nanhi/com.sagarbluezone.nanhi.Home}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: (visibleSections = new ArrayList<>()) Initialize the visibleSections before while (c.moveToNext()). and check the column string..

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
10-29 11:03:41.545 24792-24792/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)

Answer (score 0):

Your column string maybe wrong:
Try like this.

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){
     while(c.moveToNext()){
        String lb = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("label"));
        visibleSections.add(lb);
     }
}
```

Not "lebel".

Answer (score 0):

You are re assigning the array list every time your loop iterates.
remove visibleSections = new ArrayList<>(); from your loop.
and use While Loop as

```
while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
{
    //get All data here then
     cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: thanks but not working till showing index out of bound exception